# How do you search "sam.as.sam@example.com" in Google?

Tags: google-search

How do you search an email address with dot inside, such as "sam.as.sam@example.com", in Google?
When I search it with double quotation marks surrounded, the dots "." are always omitted. Any way out?

Comment: If you're looking for an exact email address use Google Advanced Search. In the "this exact word or phrase" box, you can type in the email address and it will be searched for, dots and all.

Comment: @J4G: I put "sam.as.sam@example.com" in Google advanced search, and dots and at are still ignored.

Comment: If you are including the quotation marks, it will work. If you aren't, then it may not. For instance, 3 of the top results for that particular search are stack exchange, while the last is a blog spot. You can tell the dot isn't ignored because the text that is bolded as matching in each results includes the period.

Comment: http://imgur.com/uKQ7MJ8 Here's a screenshot.